# System goes unresponsive when I close the laptop

Tags: 14.04, laptop, suspend, hibernate

Whenever I close the Laptop without locking/logging off, system goes unresponsive. Unresponsive in the sense it doesn't shows login prompt or not even some error message.
However, there is no problem when I lock/log off system before closing the lid of my laptop. I am able to use the laptop only after removing and adding the battery to the slot(bad habit, still this is the solution I found). Even the force shutdown - long press of Power button is not working.

The issue happens irrespective of running applications.

One more thing I noticed is that LED indicator for hibernate is glowing as if the laptop is hibernating when in unresponsive state.

Ubuntu version : 14.04
Hardware : Dell Inspiron 3437

Please suggest some solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you by chance have an AMD graphics card?

Comment: Nope. I am having Nvidia Geforce.

Comment: What driver are you using?

Comment: I am using "Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau(opensource).
Notify me if I am not specifying the details that you required.

Comment: Try the `nvidia-current` drivers instead (or http://bumblebee-project.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*May not be appropriate as a definitive answer but I don't have the privilege yet to post comments.*

Have you checked that you energy management is not set so that your computer goes in **hibernation** or **suspend-to-disk** mode when closing the lid (screeen) ?

If this is the case, then you have two solution:

- Set up your computer to go properly in hibernation or suspend-to-disk mode (maybe tricky)

or

- Disable set the energy mode option on "Do nothing" when closing the lid.

Regards,